# win32 api to look for files accessed by particular process

Tags: vb.net, winapi, file-access

Is there a way to look for all the files accessed by a particular process(In my case the process vb.net exe)?

I have a vb.net code that does the caching process exclusively using ngen.Now I wanna look at all the files that are being accessed by my vb process.

I have tried using process monitor and process explorer but cannot get the desired output.

Actually I am looking if there is any win32 API to get the desired output.I found API's to look for the process that is opening a particular file.

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186817/discussion-on-question-by-teja-win32-api-to-look-for-files-accessed-by-particula).

Comment: You could try the [Restart Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rstmgr/about-restart-manager).